# How to remove an action in wordpress which is inside a plugin class?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-hook

I'm using awesome support plugin for creating a ticket system in my project.

The problem I have is that support plugin will add some fields into Users Admin page which I don't want them.

I searched inside plugin code and I've found the action that is used to put the fields in users page and I want to remove that action.

I tried removing its action by using this code:

```
remove_action('wpas_all_user_profile_fields', array( WPAS_User::get_instance() , 'profile_phone_fields'), 10)
```

and it is working and the fields doesn't show on users page but I'm getting a fatal error inside my debug.log which says:

```
 PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'WPAS_User' not found in ...
```

the plugin class that is something like this

```
class WPAS_User {

  public function __construct() {
     add_action( 'wpas_all_user_profile_fields', array( $this, 'profile_phone_fields' ), 10, 1 );
 }


  public static function get_instance() {

        // If the single instance hasn't been set, set it now.
    if ( null == self::$instance ) {
            self::$instance = new self;
        }

        return self::$instance;
  }

. 
.
.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you include in your php the name of the file ?

```
<?php include('yourfile.php') ?>
```

Comment: I've tried using this code but still getting the same error:
```

if (in_array('awesome-support/awesome-support.php', apply_filters('active_plugins', get_option('active_plugins')))) {
  include_once(plugins_url('/awesome-support/includes/admin/class-admin-user.php'));
  add_action('init', 'remove_my_class_action');
  function remove_my_class_action()
  {
    $my_class = WPAS_User::get_instance();
    remove_action('wpas_all_user_profile_fields', array( $my_class , 'profile_phone_fields'), 10);
  }
}
```